# How would I add a JavaScript widget to my HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make it where if I were to click on a anchor tag, or heading, it'd make a description to the side.

## Hello world!

*clicks*

Displays text off to the side of the element I just clicked. I don't know if you guys would be able to help considering I'm not being too specific as to what I want..

Kind of like in bootstrap's JavaScript widget (If you know what I am talking about).

Comment: This is indeed very broad. In a very broad way, you could attach a click listener to the anchor tag or heading you were interested in, and then append some html after it.

Comment: you don't need JS to do what you describe, just HTML+CSS

Comment: can you give us sample code of what you have?